# DNN - Allow role to edit module content but not settings

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke-settings

I am using DNN 7.4.1 Community Edition and I would like to have a specific security role ("Editors") to have the ability to edit the **content** of every module, but not be able to edit the **settings** of every module. I know [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827585/dnn-allow-users-to-edit-content-but-not-settings) addresses this, but the answers are quite outdated and I would like to see if there is any more recent knowledge related to this issue.

I believe DotNetNuke Professional edition is now called, EVOQ Content, and due to the specificity of my issue, I would rather not upgrade for one little piece of additional functionality (also might not be an option financially). However, upgrading would seem to allow me to have more freedom over permissions.

As far as Oliver Hine's Enhanced Permission Provider for DotNetNuke, it hasn't been updated for several years. I have installed this extension, however it seems to add more headaches. As soon as it is installed, entire pages are no longer visible for any users other than the administrator role. Even after adjusting page permissions to allow "All Users" to "View Page", all of the modules are still not visible. After fumbling around with individual module permissions, certain modules were visible for certain users only after ALL permissions were granted to that role. This extension would be perfect if it worked as described (and without setting tons of individual module permissions).

So, is there any method other than the ones mentioned above that allow me to prevent the "Editors" role from accessing module settings, but still allowing them to edit the module content?

Thank you kindly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slightly newer version on github which you might have better luck with. I haven't had the time to fully test it but it's an improvement over what's on codeplex.

https://github.com/ohine/Dnn.Enhanced-Permissions-Provider

If you still run into issues, contact me on my website and I'll get things fixed up.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I did see reference to the newer version, but I wasn't able to find it during my initial internet rummaging. I'll give this option a try.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately my answer on that other post still stands as the current solution. Though Oliver might show up here and provide some insight.

> This can be achieved with DotNetNuke Professional (EVOQ) edition using the
>   extended granular permissions.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. I'll give Oliver's newer version of the Enhanced Permissions Provider a try!